ANCOVA or MODERATION?
I'm struggling with the statistics for a question I'm collecting data to answer.
My paper is about whether different meditation types can increase happiness when controlling for meaning in life. There are three meditation groups, one control. Happiness is measured before and after the meditation intervention. Meaning in life is my covariate, measured once before the intervention. Each participant was randomly assigned to a group (3 meditation conditions, one control).
I want to know:

When controlling for MIL, does meditation increase happiness?
When controlling for MIL, what is the order of how much each meditation increases happiness - order of greatest significant influence (group 1,2,3 then control)?
For different levels of MIL, which meditation is most effective for increasing happiness?

I am aware that I can answer 1 and 2 with a mixed design (within and between subject factors) ANCOVA with follow up post-hoc tests to test question 2.
However, can #3 also be answered via this ANCOVA analysis, or does #3 require a moderated regression? I believe it requires a moderated regression; however, I'm having trouble formulating how change in happiness can be included in the moderated regression model. This is because I have read about the drawback of using change scores and how using time_1 as a CV in ANCOVA is more preferable.
Regarding #3, I expect to find that the relationship between group and increases in happiness changes over different levels of MIL.
This is all absolutely spinning my head around, and I would love some help! Hopefully everything here is clear!

I'm not sure what you mean by Point 2. What do you mean by "order" in this context? Also, was Point 4 omitted or was there an additional point you wanted to consider?

What I would do is use a multilevel model.

Hi, just three points!

Although I think the approach by Shawn is defensible, I think an analysis closer to an ANCOVA would be a better approach. I don't think there is a need to model happiness at time 1. The goal should be to reduce variance in the happiness group means at time 2, which we can do by adjusting for the variables you have measured.
Although you conceptualize your effect of interest as the effect of the intervention on the change in happiness, in practice because you randomly assigned conditions, the distribution of happiness will be the same in all groups at time 1. That means the only real quantity of interest is the difference in happiness means at time 2. Again, because you randomly assigned, you don't need to adjust for any variables, including happiness or MIL at time 1, to estimate the effect of the intervention. The distributions of happiness and MIL at time 1 will be the same across the intervention groups. Slight imbalances in these variables across groups are automatically accounted for when analyzing the experiment in the traditional way (e.g., using ANOVA). The reason to adjust for MIL and happiness at time 1 is to increase precision. The estimand (i.e, the quantity being estimated) does not change when adjusting for these variables, and the validity of the inference does not depend on adjusting for them.
So, your model can look like the following (using R notation):
happiness2 ~ 1 + group + happiness1 + MIL1

To answer the moderation question (i.e., does MIL affect the effect of the intervention), you need to run a moderation analysis. One way to do this is to interact the model above with MIL, e.g.,
happiness2 ~ 1 + group + happiness1 + MIL1 + group:MIL1 + happiness1:MIL1

This allow you to essentially have a model for happiness at time 2 within each level of MIL. This model does assume the relationship between the group effect and MIL is linear, which may not be true. You can omit the interaction between happiness at time 1 and MIL; the inference is not affected by its inclusion and it doesn't make the same linearity assumption (i.e., it is a covariate that only serves to increase precision).
To test the omnibus moderation hypothesis, you can do an model comparison between the model with the group x MIL interaction and one without.
Importantly, you should use a procedure to tets your hypotheses that is agnostic the model used. This allows you to be clear about the quantities yo uwant to compare and not dependent on specifying the model in a specific way. The model can represent the assumption you want to make and the statistical choice you make to increase precision, but the quantities you actually want to estimate and compare to test yoru hypotheses are independent from the model (except in as much as the model forces those quantities to have a specific relationship). Essentially this means you will not be interpreting nay mdoel coefficients and insetad will use a marginal effects procedure to extract and compare the quantities of interest.

In R, this is what it would look like to run this analysis. First, we fit the largest model that makes the fewest assumptions. The coefficients from this model are largely uninterpretable, so we use a marginal effects procedure as implemented in marginaleffects to extract relevant quantities from the model.
#Fit the model
fit <- lm(happiness2 ~ (group + happiness1) * MIL1, data = data)

#Compute desired quantities
library(marginaleffects)

avg_predictions(fit, variables = "group", vcov = "HC3")

avg_comparisons(fit, variables = list(group = "pairwise"),
                vcov = "HC3")

These produce the covariate-adjusted group means and their pairwise contrasts, respectively. This allows you to answer the question about whether the group means differ from each other using an analysis that increases precision by adjusting for pre-treatment covariates and uses the correct robust standard error. These allow you to answer questions 1 and 2. Question 1 is answer by the comparison between each mediation group and control; question 2 is answered by the comparisons among all mediation groups. (Note that a pre-post difference is not sufficient to answer question 1 because any component of time passing could explain any difference between pre and post; only the comparison between the conditions and the control allows you to answer whether mediation had any effect. Because the control group and meditation groups have the same distribution of happiness at time 1, you only need to compare the time 2 means to answer this question.)
Below, we can test the omnibus moderation hypothesis by comparing two models, one with the group x MIL interaction (fit above) and one without (fit below).
fit2 <- lm(happiness2 ~ group + happiness1 * MIL1, data = data)

anova(fit, fit2)

If the omnibus test is significant, there is evidence of an interaction. Note, again, this assume the interaction is of a linear form, i.e., the effects of the groups change linearly with MIL. This is a strong assumption and it is possible that the real relationship is curvilinear. (Testing this in a nonlinear way is a lot harder and would require a very large sample, but if you are interested in doing so, let me know and I will adapt my answer.)
We can probe the interaction by considering the effect of group at 1 SD below the MIL mean and 1 SD above the MIL mean (here I'm assuming those values are 3 and 7, respectively).
avg_comparisons(fit, variables = list(group = "pairwise"),
                vcov = "HC3",
                newdata = datagrid(MIL1 = c(3, 7), grid_type = "coutnerfactual"),
                by = "MIL1")

Althogh this code is confusing, what it does is compute the pairwise group comparisons setting all units to have a MIL at time 1 of 3 and again setting all units to have a MIL at time 1 of 7. You can choose any values you want here.

Thank you very much for your detailed response, Noah.
That all makes sense to me. I will be using SPSS for this analysis and will see if I can make all this work on SPSS. I was thinking about requesting Johnson-Neyman information in SPSS to determine what points of MIL d the groups significantly differ and also doing a simple slopes analysis. I am unsure if this will answer my question regarding for high MIL, which kind of meditation is best to increase happiness.

Im now wondering if i can do this with an ANCOVA with a three-way interaction effect.

All three of your questions can be addressed with regression. We can fit that regression by taking the following equation (simplified a bit since there are multiple coefficients for each group):
$$
\text{Happiness} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{MIL} + \beta_2 \text{Group} + 
\beta_3 \text{Time} + \beta_4 (\text{MIL} \times \text{Group}) + \epsilon
$$
This equation accomplishes the following goals:

Since you have repeated measures, the "time" coefficient estimates the raw differences in happiness across both time points. To estimate how each group varies by time, this can be coded as an interaction, but this will increase the parameters in the model, particularly if you code three-way interactions between MIL, group, and time.
Because MIL is entered into the regression, we can estimate the main effect of meditation group on happiness.
Since mediation group simply codes the coefficients as contrasts, one can compare mean differences in happiness between each meditation group with estimated marginal means (EMMs).
By coding an interaction between MIL and group, one can see how the association between MIL and happiness changes based on group.

I don't actually think a mixed model here would be necessary so long as you code the cluster of time directly into the model as a fixed effect. I worry that using a mixed model for this may be either overkill or cause the model to crash if there isn't enough estimable variance between both times.

Thanks Shawn! That is very helpful!
